# How can I change this VBA to not return an error when deleting a row?

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to find a VBA code that would move rows from one sheet to another and found this block of code.  It works perfectly, except for when I delete an entire row.  When I delete an entire row it gives me this error.

[image]

Here's the VBA code i'm using.  How can I change it so it doesn't give me this error?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,Y:Y")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim bottomB As Long
Select Case Target.Column
    Case Is = 1
        bottomB = Sheets(Target.Value).Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        Range("A" & Target.Row).Resize(, 25).Copy Sheets(Target.Value).Cells(bottomB, 1)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Comment: `Sheets(Target.Value)` refers to a sheet in the Active Workbook whose name is contained as the value of `Target`.  Is that what you want?  This can fail in numerous ways

Comment: If Target is a multi-cell range, then `Sheets(Target.Value)` will cause a Type mismatch error. Try `Sheets(Target(1).Value)` to point to one (first) cell in the Target Range

Answer (score 0):

It will throw this error if multiple cells get changed at the same time so when the `change event` code triggers you may check to see if multiple cells are changed and then exit the code.

Try this code to see if this resolves the issue you are having.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,Y:Y")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim bottomB As Long
Select Case Target.Column
    Case Is = 1
        bottomB = Sheets(Target.Value).Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        Range("A" & Target.Row).Resize(, 25).Copy Sheets(Target.Value).Cells(bottomB, 1)
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```